# Repeating JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have this function repeat at the end of it's cycle. I tried assigning the function to a variable and calling the variable in the callback, but that failed. I tried wrapping this function in a `setInterval` function, still couldn't get it to work.

How do I get this function to run an infinite loop and repeat itself?

```
$("span.text-change").typed({
     strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
     typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
     backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
     callback: function () {
         // do stuff
     }
 });
```

This is the plugin:
[Typed JS](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LSsZr/)

Comment: Make the function a named function, so it can call itself back (outside the `typed` call, so it's a variable.

Comment: "Repeat itself": well, what is "itself"? The `.typed` call?

Comment: You will not get any result from infinite program, so why don't you just use while(true){} ?

Comment: Jon...yes. Thought that was pretty clear man.Hence repeat function.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, this was what I tried first. Call back wasn't repeating the function. I did exactly what Travelling Tech Guy below in the Answer. To no avail.

Comment: @IvanKuckir, not familiar with the function you're suggesting...

Comment: Hmm... it's hard to suggest things when I can't test them. How about a jsFiddle of the problem?

Comment: I edited my question to include jsFiddle :)

Comment: So the callback isn't being fired at all :S have to consult the plugins documentation. -> http://jsfiddle.net/LSsZr/2/

Comment: alert on the callback worked for me - on my localhost...not jsFiddle though.

Comment: Thats really strange, I suspect it is something to do with the plugin implementation, as far as at least I can tell, it all looks ok on your end. Consider raising an issue on github if no-one here can solve it -> https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/issues

Comment: Yeah, something is up. Their script is not complex either, but I couldn't see the conflict. I submitted an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your code in an interval is a good idea. However you have to check if the code execution is completed before calling it again. You could do this with a boolean variable used as flag.

```
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    flag=true;
 if( flag){
     flag=false;
    $("div").typed({
     strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
     typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
     backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
     callback: function () {
         flag=true;
         //destroy typed plugin here. See in the api if 
         //there is a method for doing that.

     }
 });

 }

}, 1000);
```

when you wan't to stop the loop you could simply destroy the timer

```
clearInterval(timerId);
```

> **edit:** I've added an option to the plugin

```
$("#typed").typed({
    strings: ["Typed.js is a jQuery plugin.", "It types out sentences."],
    typeSpeed: 30,
    backDelay: 500,
    loop:true,
    callback: function(){ alert('end'); }
});
```

edited plugin file

```
!function($){

    "use strict";

    var Typed = function(el, options){

        // for variable scope's sake
        self = this;

        // chosen element to manipulate text
        self.el = $(el);
        // options
        self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.typed.defaults, options);

        // text content of element
        self.text = self.el.text();

        // typing speed
        self.typeSpeed = self.options.typeSpeed;

        // typing speed
        self.loop = self.options.loop;

        // amount of time to wait before backspacing
        self.backDelay = self.options.backDelay;

        // input strings of text
        self.strings = self.options.strings;

        // character number position of current string
        self.strPos = 0;

        // current array position
        self.arrayPos = 0;

        // current string based on current values[] array position 
        self.string = self.strings[self.arrayPos];

        // number to stop backspacing on.
        // default 0, can change depending on how many chars
        // you want to remove at the time
        self.stopNum = 0;

        // number in which to stop going through array
        // set to strings[] array (length - 1) to stop deleting after last string is typed
        self.stopArray = self.strings.length-1;

        // All systems go!
        self.init();
    }

        Typed.prototype =  {

            constructor: Typed

            , init: function(){
                // begin the loop w/ first current string (global self.string)
                // current string will be passed as an argument each time after this
                self.typewrite(self.string, self.strPos);
                self.el.after("<span id=\"typed-cursor\">|</span>");
            }

            // pass current string state to each function
            , typewrite: function(curString, curStrPos){

                // varying values for setTimeout during typing
                // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
                var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + self.typeSpeed;

                // ------ optional ------ //
                // custom backspace delay
                // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
                //  self.backDelay = 50;
                // }
                // else{ self.backDelay = 500; }

                // containg entire typing function in a timeout
                setTimeout(function() {

                    // make sure array position is less than array length
                    if (self.arrayPos < self.strings.length){

                        // start typing each new char into existing string
                        // curString is function arg
                        self.el.text(self.text + curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

                        // check if current character number is the string's length
                        // and if the current array position is less than the stopping point
                        // if so, backspace after backDelay setting
                        if (curStrPos > curString.length && self.arrayPos < self.stopArray){
                            clearTimeout();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
                            }, self.backDelay);
                        }

                        // else, keep typing
                        else{
                            // add characters one by one
                            curStrPos++;
                            // loop the function
                            self.typewrite(curString, curStrPos);
                            // if the array position is at the stopping position
                            // finish code, on to next task
                            if (self.arrayPos == self.stopArray && curStrPos == curString.length){
                                // animation that occurs on the last typed string
                                // place any finishing code here

                                if(self.loop){
                                        self.arrayPos=0;
                                        curStrPos=0;
                                }else{
                                self.options.callback();
                                clearTimeout();}
                            }
                        }
                    }

                // humanized value for typing
                }, humanize);

            }

            , backspace: function(curString, curStrPos){

                // varying values for setTimeout during typing
                // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
                var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + self.typeSpeed;

                setTimeout(function() {

                        // ----- this part is optional ----- //
                        // check string array position
                        // on the first string, only delete one word
                        // the stopNum actually represents the amount of chars to
                        // keep in the current string. In my case it's 14.
                        // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
                        //  self.stopNum = 14;
                        // }
                        //every other time, delete the whole typed string
                        // else{
                        //  self.stopNum = 0;
                        // }

                    // ----- continue important stuff ----- //
                        // replace text with current text + typed characters
                        self.el.text(self.text + curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

                        // if the number (id of character in current string) is 
                        // less than the stop number, keep going
                        if (curStrPos > self.stopNum){
                            // subtract characters one by one
                            curStrPos--;
                            // loop the function
                            self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
                        }
                        // if the stop number has been reached, increase 
                        // array position to next string
                        else if (curStrPos <= self.stopNum){
                            clearTimeout();
                            self.arrayPos = self.arrayPos+1;
                            // must pass new array position in this instance
                            // instead of using global arrayPos
                            self.typewrite(self.strings[self.arrayPos], curStrPos);
                        }

                // humanized value for typing
                }, humanize);   

            }

        }

    $.fn.typed = function (option) {
        return this.each(function () {
          var $this = $(this)
            , data = $this.data('typed')
            , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
          if (!data) $this.data('typed', (data = new Typed(this, options)))
          if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
        });
    }

    $.fn.typed.defaults = {
        strings: ["These are the default values...", "You know what you should do?", "Use your own!", "Have a great day!"],
        // typing and backspacing speed
        typeSpeed: 0,
        // time before backspacing
        backDelay: 500,
        loop:false,
        // ending callback function
        callback: function(){ null }
    }


}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: hi yes, I saw your jsfiddle. the problem is you have to kill the current typed in the callback. you have to see in the plugins api if there is a method for doing that. I can't find the plugin so I can't help. maybe you have a link?

Comment: Their docs are super non-existant really. View plugin here... http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Comment: hi, i think the problem is that the callback function of the plugin is not working...

Comment: I found why it is not working on jsfiddle :-) jsfiddle uses the script from this link http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/js/typed.custom.js if you look at the source you'll see that this version does not implements the callback option.

Comment: Interesting...I needed a live link to the js, so I just pulled that one.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with the updated script version from github? https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/js/typed.js

Comment: Can't use GitHUb as a CDN. But I did the next best thing and uploaded the script somewhere. jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/LSsZr/7/

Comment: only second sentence is repeating! how to repeat both?

Answer (score 5):

Typed.js author here. I think it's friggin awesome people like my code enough to dig through it and make more features work. I definitely plan to make looping a default function you can set, but for now here's a fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/LSsZr/8/

**Main Changes**

```
self.stopArray = self.strings.length;
// instead of self.stopArray = self.strings.length-1;
```

This makes the stopArray variable allow for it to continue backspacing once the last string is typed. Otherwise, it'll stop once the last one is printed.

---

```
// if (self.arrayPos == self.stopArray && curStrPos == curString.length){
// animation that occurs on the last typed string
// place any finishing code here
//  self.options.callback();
//    clearTimeout();
// }
```

The above has been **removed**. It checked for the last string being typed, and fired off a function when the condition was met. For a loop we don't want that.

---

```
else{
   self.arrayPos = 0;
   self.typewrite(self.string, self.strPos);
}
```

The above has been added as an else to the following if statement...

```
if (self.arrayPos < self.strings.length){
```

So if the array position is less than the amount of strings in the array, type them. Else, reset the position to 0, and run the original function again.

Go ahead and use the code in the jsfiddle as your typed.js file, and then run it normally on the page you want. There's no longer a callback() though!

Let me know your thoughts / questions!

**EDIT**
Looks like someone here added a loop to the plugin, but it only loops the last sentence over and over :p

You've got to reset the string in the array being sent to the typewrite function. That isn't happening in the other solution.

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly what I was looking for...your plug-in created quite the thread of comments here lol. Which is a pretty sweet one btw.

Comment: mattboldt has 51 reputation :D thanks for typed.js matt. this is great.

Comment: @DogukanCavus Thanks! I should note, however, that all the code shown in this post is using the old jQuery implementation. Typed.js is now jQuery-free with an updated API.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(func = function () {
      $(".element").typed({
          strings: ['Statement One', 
            'Satemante Two',
          'Statemante Three', ''],
          typeSpeed: 40, // typing speed
          backDelay: 2000,
          callback: function (){
            func();
          }
      });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".typed-text").typed({
    strings: ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"],
    typeSpeed: 10,
    backDelay: 1500,
    loop: !0, // here
    startDelay: 1000,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var myFunc = function() {
  $("span.text-change").typed({
     strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
     typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
     backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
     callback: function () {
         myFunc();
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: still just runs once and doesn't repeat the function.

Comment: That tells me that your 'callback' probably isn't being fired by the typed jquery plugin.

Comment: Call backs works. I tested an alert. jsFiddle is now in my question FYI.

Comment: Strange, I ran your jsFiddle with an alert, and no alert came up :s

Comment: This means `callback` is never called. In that case, just make the last line of the function `myFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

Just add property loop:1. for infinite looping

$(".typed-text").typed({
    strings: ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"],
    typeSpeed: 10,
    backDelay: 1500,
    loop: 1, // here
});